# how long will facebook plugin work with http?

Tags: cordova-facebook

While running my Cordova app in Chrome using:

```
cordova run browser
```

I see the following message in the console:

```
The method FB.getLoginStatus will soon stop working when called from http pages. Please update your site to use https for Facebook Login. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/06/08/enforce-https-facebook-login/
```

Is this a concern with this plugin?

Comment: It's already no longer working. Though, you can still use http in development mode with localhost.

Comment: except i am in development mode

Comment: You should be able to use http only in development mode indefinitely but it definitely is a concern if you're going to deploy this to production.